# Get src of scripts and styles loaded in current page

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

In Wordpress I need to know the src of all scripts and style loaded in the current page (so in Homepage I only need Homepage's scripts and styles).

I've tried the code below but I think these are ALL the scripts and styles of my Wordpress site. In fact the frontend doesn't work properly (see image).

My scope is to get all styles' hrefs, all scripts' srcs and then print them (`<link href`..., `<script src`...) where I want.

My custom code in my theme's functions.php

```
/**
*   Creo gli array dei percorsi 
*/
$include_css = array();
$include_js = array();

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'ac');
function ac()
{
    /**
    *   Carico le variabili globali contententi stili e scripts
    */
    global $wp_styles, $wp_scripts;
    global $include_css, $include_js;


    /**
    *   Dichiaro variabili d'utilità
    */
    $base_url = get_site_url();
    $external_url = "//";
    $css_extension = ".css";
    $js_extension = ".js";

    /**
    *   Per ogni stile
    */
    foreach ( $wp_styles->registered as $registered )
    {
        $css = $registered->src;

        /** 
        *   Se finisce con .css 
        */
        if (endsWith($css, $css_extension)) 
        {
            /** 
            *   Se non inizia con "//" (risorsa esterna) e se non contiene già l'url di base 
            */
            if((!startsWith($css, $external_url)) && (!startsWith($css, $base_url)))
            {
                $include_css[] = $base_url."".$css;
            }
            else
            {
                $include_css[] = $css;
            }   

        }

    }
    $wp_styles->registered = array();

    /**
    *   Per ogni script
    */
    foreach ( $wp_scripts->registered as $registered )
    {
        $js = $registered->src;

        /** 
        *   Se finisce con .js 
        */
        if (endsWith($js, $js_extension)) 
        {
            /** 
            *   Se non inizia con "//" (risorsa esterna) e se non contiene già l'url di base 
            */
            if((!startsWith($js, $external_url)) && (!startsWith($js, $base_url)))
            {
                $include_js[] = $base_url."".$js;
            }
            else
            {
                $include_js[] = $js;
            }           
        }
    }
    $wp_scripts->registered = array();
}
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) 
{
    // search backwards starting from haystack length characters from the end
    return $needle === "" || strrpos($haystack, $needle, -strlen($haystack)) !== FALSE;
}
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) 
{
    // search forward starting from end minus needle length characters
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== FALSE);
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'b' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'c' );

function b()
{
    global $include_css, $include_js;
    foreach($include_js as $src)
    {
        echo 
        "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"$src\"></script>
        ";
    }
}
function c()
{
    global $include_css, $include_js;
    foreach($include_css as $src)
    {
        echo 
        "
            <link  rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"$src\"/>
        ";
    }
}
```

The frontend after adding my custom code:
[image]

Comment: Are you wanting only styles and scripts registered with Wordpress using `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style`, or including any scripts and styles that may be injected into the output directly, like in the theme files?

Comment: It looks like your goal is to move all Javascript to the footer, and put all the CSS in the document head.  Perhaps you would be better served by a plugin like [Scripts to Footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scripts-to-footerphp/) or the more advanced [Better Wordpress Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/) that will allow you to concatenate and reorder Javascript.

Comment: I've already tried these plugin but they have broken my layout.
I need only scripts and styles used in the current page
Thanks for your interesting  @shshaw